# How to disable splitting into new line in prettier?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using Prettier for better formatting of the code. How do I disable the new line?

Before Saving:

[image]

After Saving:

[image]

I prefer them just to be like on Image 1 on saving.
How can I disable it so that it won't be like on image 2?

Comment: Please post text, not links to images of text.

Answer (score 0):

Prettier is quite strict so doesn't let you change much. There are a list of options on the docs, I think this is the closest to what you want: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#jsx-brackets

It might take a while to get used to it, but I quite like having the props on each line as it makes it easier to track changes in git history, so maybe over time it'll grow on you too :)